# Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(buildTarget)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, npm, npm-package

I'm trying to initialize my angular application where I recently added ng-matero. Given this, I started using the `npm run hmr` command, but every time I try it always gives the same error. I looked in some places and saw that running the commands `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.12 --force` and `npm i @angular/cli@16` could solve my problem, but that didn't work either.

This is a copy of my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "manager-front-end-v3.1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "lint": "npm run lint:ts && npm run lint:scss",
    "lint:ts": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "lint:scss": "stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\" --fix",
    "hmr": "ng serve --hmr --disable-host-check"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@ng-matero/extensions": "^17.0.0",
    "@ng-matero/extensions-moment-adapter": "^17.0.0",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^6.2.0",
    "@ngx-formly/material": "^6.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-matero": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^16.0.1",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^11.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "photoviewer": "^3.9.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "screenfull": "^6.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.19.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "parse5": "^7.1.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "stylelint": "^16.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order": "^4.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^14.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^36.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

If you need it, this is the github link: https://github.com/Galleazzo/Manager-Front-End-V3.1

I'm just trying to start the project to start developing. I already changed @angular-devkit/build-angular" but nothing happened. I want the project to initialize